# Git Repository State:Conflicts

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I did some changes in my local master branch then followed following steps :

1) Commit in Local Master.
2)Pull from Remote Master to Local Master
3)Rebase Local Master

After rebasing several conflicts arised. I handled all the conflicts and made the required changes in my local master. and then when i did commit in my local master, it gives **Repository State:Conflicts** also when i try to merge then also it gives

[image]

How to solve these problem when so that i can push it to Remote Master.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are not adding the files to index.

Go to Team > Add To Index.
then Rebase > Continue Rebase

then commit in Your Local Master and Push